# How to avoid bulk data duplicate values when insert in to a table in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The problem im trying to solve is about avoiding duplicate data getting into my table. I'm using xml to send bulk data to a stored procedure. The procedure I wrote works with 100, 200 records. But when it comes to 20000 of them there is a time out exception.

This is the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (Page_No varchar(MAX))
DECLARE @TEMP2 TABLE (Page_No varchar(MAX))

INSERT INTO @TEMP(Page_No)
    SELECT 
        CAST(CC.query('data(PageId)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Page_No
    FROM 
        @XML.nodes('DocumentElement/CusipsFile') AS tt(CC)

INSERT INTO @TEMP2(Page_No)
    SELECT Page_No 
    FROM tbl_Cusips_Pages

INSERT INTO tbl_Cusips_Pages(Page_No, Download_Status)
    SELECT Page_No, 'False'
    FROM @TEMP
    WHERE Page_No NOT IN (SELECT Page_No FROM @TEMP
                          INTERSECT
                          SELECT Page_No FROM @TEMP2)
```

How can I solve this? Is there a better way to write this procedure?

Comment: how much data is in page_no. do you really need an nvarchar max? You can just left join the tables on page_no and only insert where tbl_cusips_pages.Page_No is null. having a smaller data type will help the join be faster.

Comment: 1) how big are the records? 2) how long is the timeout? 3) post the table definition for `tbl_Cusips_Pages` including keys and indexes.  4) if possible, post the query plan.

Comment: Also, have you timed each step, and if so, how much time is spent on each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already suggested, NVARCHAR(MAX) column/variable is very slow and has limited options. If you can change it, it would help a lot.

```
MERGE tbl_Cusips_Pages
    USING (
       SELECT 
          CAST(CC.query('data(PageId)') AS NVARCHAR(4000))
       FROM 
        @XML.nodes('DocumentElement/CusipsFile') AS tt(CC)
    ) AS source (Page_No)
        ON tbl_Cusips_Pages.Page_No = source.Page_No
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT (Page_No, Download_Status)
            VALUES (source.Page_No, 'false')
```

Anyway, your query is not that bad either, just put the queries directly into the third one (TEMP2 one for sure) instead of inserting the data into the table variables. Table variables are quite slow in comparison.

Comment: Thank you so much mate, Really saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

Replace last INSERT Statement with following Script, I have replace `IN` Clause With `NOT EXISTS` that may help you for better performance.

```
DECLARE @CommanPageNo TABLE (Page_No varchar(MAX))
INSERT INTO @CommanPageNo SELECT Page_No FROM @TEMP
                      INTERSECT
                      SELECT Page_No FROM @TEMP2


INSERT INTO tbl_Cusips_Pages(Page_No, Download_Status)
SELECT Page_No, 'False'
FROM @TEMP
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @CommanPageNo WHERE Page_No=@CommanPageNo.Page_No)
```